# how to display the taxonomy terms in hierarchies order?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-taxonomy

I have a vocabulary which displays the terms in the hierarchies order like the following.

- parent1

  - child1
  - child2
- parent2

  - child1
- parent3
- parent4

  - child1
  - child2
  - child3

This displays in taxonomy manager.

I want to create a page on which I call a function and pass the vid and displays the taxonomy terms of that vocabulary in hierarchies order just like in taxonomy manager.
I used the following code but it displays only the taxonomy terms not in a tree order.

```
$vid = 26;
$tree = taxonomy_get_tree($vid);
foreach($tree as $term) {
  $output =  l($term->name, taxonomy_term_path($term));
  if ($term->children) {
    $output .= theme('illogica_category_tree', $term->children);
  }
}

print $output;
```

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
$tree = extranet_get_nested_tree((int)$vid, null, $tid);
```

With this:

```
function extranet_get_nested_tree($terms = array(), $max_depth = NULL, $parent = 0, $parents_index = array(), $depth = 0) {
  if (is_int($terms)) {
    $terms = taxonomy_get_tree($terms);
  }

  foreach($terms as $term) {
    foreach($term->parents as $term_parent) {
      if ($term_parent == $parent) {
        $return[$term->tid] = $term;
      }
      else {
        $parents_index[$term_parent][$term->tid] = $term;
      }
    }
  }

  foreach($return as &$term) {
    if (isset($parents_index[$term->tid]) && (is_null($max_depth) || $depth <     $max_depth)) {
      $term->children = extranet_get_nested_tree($parents_index[$term->tid],     $max_depth, $term->tid, $parents_index, $depth + 1);
    }
  }
  return $return;
}
```

And to print it out:

```
    function extranet_output_nested_tree($tree) {
    if (count($tree)) {
        $output = '<ul class="nested-taxonomy-tree">';
        foreach ($tree as $term) {
            $output .= '<li class="taxonomy-term">';
            $output .= t($term->name); //, taxonomy_term_path($term));
            if ($term->children) {
                $output .= extranet_output_nested_tree( $term->children);
            }
            $output .= '</li>';
        }
        $output .= '</ul>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Excellent solution! I have taken it without "own bicycle". Thank you Friend!
I've just wrapped it  into my function from hook_menu

Answer (score 0):

`taxonomy_get_tree()` should return the terms in the correct order, but the array is flat rather than nested. See [taxonomy_get_tree()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/6) for more information and some sample functions to get a nested array.

Comment: I have checked that before posting here. I did not found any solution there.

Comment: There is at least one satisfactory solution ATM. Check for example https://api.drupal.org/comment/52303#comment-52303 which runs in O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution `

```
  foreach($terms as $term) {
    foreach($term->parents as $term_parent) {
      if ($term_parent == $parent) {
        $return[$term->tid] = $term;
      }
      else {
        $parents_index[$term_parent][$term->tid] = $term;
      }
    }
  }

  foreach($return as &$term) {
    if (isset($parents_index[$term->tid]) && (is_null($max_depth) || $depth < $max_depth)) {
      $term->children = taxonomy_get_nested_tree($parents_index[$term->tid], $max_depth, $term->tid, $parents_index, $depth + 1);
    }
  }

  return $return;
}

function output_taxonomy_nested_tree($tree) {
    if (count($tree)) {
        $output = '<ul class="nav navbar-nav">';
        foreach ($tree as $term) {            
             $output .= '<li class="taxonomy-term">' . l($term->name, "taxonomy/term/". $term->tid);


            if ($term->children) {
                $output .= output_taxonomy_nested_tree($term->children);
            }
            $output .= '</li>';
        }
        $output .= '</ul>';
    }
    return $output;
}
$tree= taxonomy_get_nested_tree(2,10);
$output=output_taxonomy_nested_tree($tree);
echo $output;`
```

If you want to print it in the specific region you needed just assign the output to a variable in  preprocessor function and print the variable in the page tpl file.

> $output=output_taxonomy_nested_tree($tree);
>       echo $output;`

to

> $variables['output'] .=output_taxonomy_nested_tree($tree);

place the line

```
<?php print $output;?>
```

in your page tpl file